# View crashes on IOS Simulator when returning into it

Tags: ios, view, crash, xib

I have two XIBs setup, one starts up and there is a button on the XIB that then loads a view (separate XIB) which has an RSS feed.

On the second Xib which is the RSS feed i have a navigation button named home that returns to the original Xib. That all works fine however when i click the button on the original Xib to return to the second Xib again, the IOS simulator crashes.

I imagine i have to release the original view but i am unsure how to do this? any tips.

Here is the code i am using to move to the second Xib (so this would be being executed again when i attempt to go to the RSS view).

```
- (IBAction)changeratings:(id)sender
{
    RSSTableViewController *rss2 = [[RSSTableViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:rss2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: what is your crash log?

Comment: i will crash it on the device and post for you

Comment: Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x700166a2
Crashed Thread:  0

Comment: i am fairly sure its because im not releasing something in the RSS nib and then trying to hit it again so i need to 'release' the nib or the view, any help ? :) (thats just my gut feeling)

Answer (score 0):

it is crashing because you are just allocating the RSSTableViewController ,you are not initing it any nib interface ,thats why.

you have to init it with `initWithNibName` . init like below

```
RSSTableViewController *rss2 = [[RSSTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RSSTableViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: it is because he has nib file of RSSTableViewController & he wants to use that , thats it

Comment: i've tried this and it didn't work. If it helps Xcode is saying Thread 1: EXC BAD_ACCESS (CODE 1 etc etc)

Comment: the weird thing is that the first time around the button works but i use HOME to go back to home Xib and then hit the button to go back to the RSS page and crash.

Comment: crash log top bit 
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x700166a2
Crashed Thread:  0

Comment: i am fairly sure its because im not releasing something in the RSS nib and then trying to hit it again so i need to 'release' the nib or the view, any help ? :) (thats just my gut feeling)

Comment: ok i have tracked crash down, this is my code in main.m //

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
} 


its crashing on the second time this code is hit. So the first time i hit the button to load second xib its fine, when i go back and try to go to xib again it crashes on that code.

specifically it appears to be the return line.

Comment: one more update. I put a debug exception on all exceptions in the breakpoint menu and it just crashes to what I've posted as opposed to any specific line

Comment: ok more info, in the background when my app launches despite it working until the xib problem, it does say applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of the launch. related?

and if so how do i fix?

Comment: i think you have deleted first starting arrow on storyboard

Comment: otherwise you have forgotten to assign rootViewController property

Comment: not using storyboards. i have a root controller here is my app delegate section for that

Comment: Under "did finish section"
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] init] autorelease];
    ViewController11 *vc11 = [[[ViewController11 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController11" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
    [navigationController pushViewController:vc11 animated:NO];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc11;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}